# What does "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently" mean

Tags: php, email

What does the following error mean when trying to send `mail()` in PHP?

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently

What are the causes etc. I notice that this happens when trying to send mail from the same domain. eg. website: example.com to email contact@example.com. If I try to send to test@gmail.com or even test@example2.com, it works

Answer (score 4):

It means exactly what it says:
The mail couldn't be delivered to the target address, this however could have several reasons.
Does it say anything else, like an error returned from the target mail server?

If other domains are working I guess your local mail server does have some configuration to not allow what you are trying.
Please check the configuration of you local mailserver:
Does the target mailbox exist? --> create it or add a CatchAll-Rule
May it does not allow local mail receiving? --> add "localhost" to its whitelist

Answer (score 1):

I found out it usually is caused by the missing receiving email account

Comment: This error is **ALWAYS** returned by the last MTA in the delivery chain, the reason is up to the MTA and not disclosed